# pure functional programming with C++

Tags: c++, functional-programming

I believe that the new features in c++ do allow pure functional programming in this gigantic language if the programmer intends to do so. I tried one below, with no variables at all and loops only based on recursion, as pure-functional. I wonder whether there can be some practical benefits in doing this with c++. Well, c++ is faster than any other functional languages, and in this way, although it may be quite headachy to the programmer, it directly brings down all the benefits and safety of the functional programming paradigm. Or perhaps the current-day c++ compilers are too dumb to effectively optimise such code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdint>

int main() {
    std::function<const uint64_t (const uint64_t)> factorial = [&](const uint64_t n)
    -> const uint64_t {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    };
    {
        enum { NUM_ITERATION = 20 };
        std::function<void (const unsigned)> loop = [&](const unsigned n) -> void {
            if (n == 0) {
                return;
            }
            std::cout << factorial(NUM_ITERATION - n) << '\n';
            loop(n - 1);
        };
        loop(NUM_ITERATION);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should examine the output of your compiler (with optimization enabled) to form your own view, otherwise you'll get vague generalizations and guesses. Some and possibly all decent C++ compilers are capable of tail call optimization in principle, but I've never checked whether that use of `std::function` impedes this (for example, does the compiler even bother trying to determine that nothing assigns to `loop` elsewhere?). The transformation of `factorial` into a tail recursion is likely beyond a C++ compiler, although I'd be happy to be wrong on that. See also `constexpr`, though.

Comment: Doing functional programming in C++ is like assembling a wristwatch with a jack-hammer. In all seriousness, the lack of GC, the lack of general tail calls (even the best compilers can only do it in _very_ limited cases) and other relevant optimisations, the lack of datatypes, and the entirely inadequate syntax -- to name just a few reasons -- is prohibitive for anything but simple patterns.

Comment: Well, C++ *can* be faster than other functional programming languages but keep in mind C++ compilers generally optimize for imperative styles while compilers for functional programming languages are dedicated to optimizing functional programs (and take advantage of all the decades of research in that field) so that might not necessarily be the case here. There are some functional optimizations that are just not possible in C++ at all (such as stream fusion) because you can't guarantee that something has no side effects. Also, C++ syntax is not well suited to purely functional code.

Comment: The compiler has generated so many hidden classes in your example that the "pure functional" paradigm is not even optimal as a functional paradigm. What you should do is drift away from pure-XXX paradigm and accept c++ as it is: a multi-paradigm language that uses the best features of all paradigms. Both std::function and lambdas generate unnecessary objects that you could optimize away by doing actual useful stuff with c++.